# sql - rental shop diagram

Tags: sql

I am new to the forum and to the sql, and I've tried searching for an answer but I can't find specifically what I need. Here is the deal. For a collage project I have to make a game rental web application. I've come up with an idea what should it do and for that I've created my ER model. But I'm not sure if it's good. The thing is not to do very complicated application.

Customer can come to the shop of game rental, and make a reservation, beside other things he can choose start date, end date, and game. The price is based on the console type.

I have attached ERD diagram and wonder if it's any good?
[image]

Comment: it's a start! nice!\

Comment: You need to add customer_id to the Orders table (FK). You should have a 1:1 relationship between Orders and Customer_Return, a Game cannot be returned multiple times for the same Order and an Order has only one Game, right? I would change order_id  for Customer_Return to be customer_return_id as PK and add order_id as FK for the Orders table. I would also have a 1:1 relationship between Customer_Return and Penalty, add penalty_id as PK for the Penalty table, remove order_id, customer_id and add customer_return_id as FK for the Customer_Return table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is good but I'd change the Penalty table because it's redundant; you already have stored the relationship between `customer_id` and `order_id` in Order.  For clarity, you could merge the tables Order and CustomerReturn into one that stores everything:

```
Order
-----
order_id (PK)
game_id (FK)
customer_id (FK)
order_date
order_due_return_date
order_effective_return_date
penalty_id (FK)
```

and recycle the Penalty table to store the type of penalty and their price:

```
Penalty
-------
penalty_id
penalty_title
penalty_price
```

Comment: I have order table to track transactions and make sure I do not have situation when two customers rent one game (only one copy)? Q - would be beneficial to add Customer Address table with one to one relationship?

Comment: Only if you want to store multiple addresses for one customer.